# OS X KEXT printing pointers result in <ptr>

Tags: c, macos, kernel

So doing the standard printf using "%p" to print a pointer, results in the literal string "< ptr >" being printed. As in:

```
kernel[0]: getvnode zp <ptr> with vp 0 zfsvfs <ptr> vfs <ptr>
```

Which is a bit tedious. I thought for a second it could be connected to SIP, since it has only started with it since El Capitan. But my csrutil show "debug" to be disabled. (KEXT VM has all SIP disabled).

I am guessing Apple had something in mind here, but I would like to be able to debug :)

Comment: Huh. I'm guessing this is to avoid leaking kernel pointer values to userspace, which could potentially render ASLR worthless.

Answer (score 3):

I was told to pass "-show_pointers" to nvram's boot-args and I can confirm that makes everything works as expected.

Comment: Since 10.11.2, this will no longer work, as Apple has decided to remove it. You should run the "Development" kernel (or Debug kernel) and use the sysctl "hide_kernel_pointers". Alternatively some nvram hackery detailed here  https://github.com/openzfsonosx/zfs/issues/461#issuecomment-177052785

Comment: Can you provide some resources to using the Development kernel and using that sysctl please?